# JApplet contain a frame, or JApplet alone?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, japplet

I have this project that I need to publish, but don't know which way will be best. Can somebody help me please.

I have a Gui application(Jframe). In there I have a Jpanel that contains some animations (implement runnable). So in my main method I would call the constructor first, so everything display nicely, then called Runner.start(). (Thread)

So basically the gui pop up and then the animation happens, to be specific the animation is just the title of my program that slides in.

Now I want to put this on the website so my students can use.
I do not want to use java web start, i want this to act as an applet.

So do i put this jframe into my applet?
or should I convert this whole thing from jframe to japplet? and is this applet need to implement Runnable?

The thing that bug me is that Japplet has no main method, so how can I specified when my Jpanel can execute its animation? I want the animation to occur after everything has load up on the screen, not before.

I guess put it as the last statement of init() method? Correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: Seems like you're seeking a tutorial on applets.

Comment: This could help: [Lesson: Java Applets (Oracle)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)

Comment: A `Runnable` for animations ... please make sure you perform all Swing operations on the Event Dispatch Thread and not just on some random `Thread`. Typically, a `javax.swing.Timer` is used for Swing animations

Comment: *"I guess put it as the last statement of init() method? Correct me if I am wrong."*  Yes, but if going with applets, you would also likely want to pause the animation in `stop()` and resume it in `start()`.  (But go with JWS, as described in my answer.)

Answer (score 3):

> I have a Gui application(Jframe). .. I want to put this on the website so my students can use.

While it is possible to convert the frame to an applet, a better option is to launch the frame from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 2):

you can do both:

### MainGui

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
public class MainGui extends JPanel {
    public MainGui() {
        this(null);
    } 
    public MainGui(MyJApplet applet) {
        this.applet = applet;
        if (!isApplet()) {
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        } else
            frame = null;
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        // setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MainGui.this.run();
            }
        });
    }
    String title() {
        return "Title";
    }
    public void addContent() {
        add(new JLabel("add content! top"));
    }
    void run() {
        if (isApplet()) addContent();
        else {
            frame.setTitle(title());
            frame.getContentPane().add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            addContent();
            frame.pack();
            System.out.println(getSize());
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    boolean isApplet() {
        return applet != null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainGui(null);
    }
    protected final JFrame frame;
    protected final MyJApplet applet;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
}
```

### MyJApplet

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
public class MyJApplet extends JApplet {
    public void start() {

    }
    public void init() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        addContent();
    }
    public void addContent() {
        getContentPane().add(new MainGui(this), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainGui(null);
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
}
```